# Restore 200+ mysql databases

Tags: mysql

I have 200+ mysql database dump in tar.gz format. Restoring all of them one by one is very time consuming. Is there any way so I can restore all these database in a single transaction.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: No need to tar a single file, just gz compression is enough. Then something like `zcat $file | mysql` in a loop would have done the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bash:

```
for file in *.tar.gz; do 
  echo "processing $file";
  zcat $file | mysql;
done
```

Comment: Will the mysql binary properly deal with tarred/gzipped data?

Comment: @ErikA zcat is supposed to take care of that, yet tar.gz probably means it was tarred first for some reason, don't know if that is also handled by zcat.

Comment: @Xeross - Hubert didn't include zcat in his initial answer, which is when I posted that comment.

Comment: @ Hubert, thanks for the tips mate. I'm getting this error "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
processing dcv.sql.gz
zcat: %file.gz: No such file or directory". If I try with mysql -uroo -pPASSWORD, getting this error "zcat: %file.gz: No such file or directory".

Comment: use "$", not "%", in windows cmd you write a loop differently and use double %: `%varname%`

Answer (score 1):

No, because transactions don't cross database boundaries.  On the other hand, if you want to load 200+ databases with a single command, just script the process.